# Display results from api after user input

Tags: javascript, rest, dom, input

I'm learning JS and I need some help figuring out why my info isn't getting populated in the html.  I'm just trying to get the basic functionality to work, so that I can continue to expand on it.

User is supposed to input a 3 digit route value, which will then return all the route information from an api call.  I was able to get the route info to display earlier when I got the api call set up, but I'm struggling to figure why it's not displaying now that I tried adding in a feature to allow the user to input the route.  [See attached pen](https://codepen.io/skyliner33v/pen/JJevKP)

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
    <h1 id='header'>Route Info</h1>
    <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter 3 digit route ex 005" >
    <input type="button" value="Get Route" onclick="getRoute()">
    <br>
    <p id = 'p'><span id="routeInfo"></span></p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var route = $('#input');
    getRoute.click(function() {
        var scriptTag = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
        scriptTag.src = "https://wsdot.wa.gov/Traffic/api/Bridges/ClearanceREST.svc/GetClearancesAsJson?AccessCode=59a077ad-7ee3-49f8-9966-95a788d7052f&callback=myCallback&Route=" + route;
        document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
        var myCallback = function(data) {
            var myarray = Array.prototype.slice.call(data);
            document.getElementById("routeInfo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myarray);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Check the browser's console, looks like the main issue is that `getRoute is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are jumping through a lot of hoops you don't need to. As long as you are using Jquery, you should look into getting the api data with an ajax request. It's much easier and more intuitive. Also you have a few problems such as trying to get the input value with `var route = $('#input');` which return the actual input element. You are also processing the returned data in a way that won't work.

Here's a basic example to get you going on (IMO) a better track:

```
function getRoute() {
   var route = $('#input').val();
   var url = "https://wsdot.wa.gov/Traffic/api/Bridges/ClearanceREST.svc/GetClearancesAsJson?AccessCode=59a077ad-7ee3-49f8-9966-95a788d7052f&Route=" + route;

    $.ajax({url: url, success: function(data){
        var retValue = "";
        var i = 0
        for(i; i< data.length; i++) {
            retValue += data[i].BridgeName + "<br>"
        }
        document.getElementById("routeInfo").innerHTML = retValue;

    }});

}
```

Comment: This makes way more sense!  Thank you Mark!  I tried using ajax earlier and i couldn't get it to work, mostly because I couldn't figure out how it worked.  I stumbled across using the scriptTag stuff because I played around with it long enough that it eventually worked.  One problem though is using your method isn't bringing anything up.  Console says it's not allowing the cross origin request.

Comment: Holy crap @MarkM I got it to work!  I added dataType: 'jsonp', to the ajax request and it worked wonderfully.  Thank you so much for the help!!!  Now on to the next struggle.

Comment: Oh yeah, it looks like wsdot isn't sending CORS headers -- but at least they have JSONP. Glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend functionality in the `getRoute.click` callback to run, you need to rewrite that as a method `function getRoute()`, or get the button element via jQuery and assign that to the variable getRoute. As it stands, you have the click method wired via the markup to a function named getRoute which does not exist. In the JS you are trying to register a click event to a jQuery object named getRoute which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

getRoute needs to be a global function for it to be called from html :

```
getRoute = (function() {
```

Also, myCallback needs to be a global function for it to be called from your loaded script (just remove the var):

```
myCallback = function(data) {
```